# Necessary and sufficient condition on joint MGF for independence

Tags: probability, independence, joint-distribution, moment-generating-function

Suppose I have a joint moment generating function $M_{X,Y}(s,t)$ for a joint distribution with CDF $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$. Is $M_{X,Y}(s,t)=M_{X,Y}(s,0)⋅M_{X,Y}(0,t)$ both a necessary *and sufficient* condition for independence of $X$ and $Y$? I checked a couple of textbooks, which only mentioned *necessity:*

$$F_{X,Y}(x,y)=F_X(x)\cdot F_Y(y) \implies M_{X,Y}(s,t)=M_X(s) \cdot M_Y(t)$$

That result is clear as independence implies $M_{X,Y}(s,t)=\mathbb{E}(e^{sX+tY})=\mathbb{E}(e^{sX}) \mathbb{E}(e^{tY})$. Since the MGFs of the marginals are determined by the joint MGF we have:

$$X,Y\text{ independent} \implies M_{X,Y}(s,t)=M_{X,Y}(s,0)⋅M_{X,Y}(0,t)$$

But after searching online I found [only a fleeting reference, without proof, to the converse](http://math.tntech.edu/ISR/Introduction_to_Probability/Distributions_of_Functions/thispage/newnode10.html). Is the following sketch proof workable?

Given a joint MGF $M_{X,Y}(s,t)$, this uniquely determines the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ and their MGFs, 
$M_X(s)=M_{X,Y}(s,0)$ and $M_Y(t)=M_{X,Y}(0,t)$. The marginals alone are compatible with many other possible joint distributions, and uniquely determine a joint distribution in which $X$ and $Y$ are independent, with CDF $F_{X,Y}^{\text{ind}}(x,y)=F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)$ and MGF:

$$M_{X,Y}^{\text{ind}}(s,t) = M_X(s) \cdot M_Y(t) = M_{X,Y}(s,0)⋅M_{X,Y}(0,t)$$

So if we are given, for our original MGF, that $M_{X,Y}(s,t) = M_{X,Y}(s,0)⋅M_{X,Y}(0,t)$, this is sufficient to show $M_{X,Y}(s,t) = M_{X,Y}^{\text{ind}}(s,t)$. Then by the uniqeness of MGFs, our original joint distribution has $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_{X,Y}^{\text{ind}}(x,y) = F_X(x) \cdot F_Y(y)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, that's the necessary and sufficient condition for independence not only for two random variables but also for a (finite) sequence of random variables. Check out for example P.2 on page 242 of [Probability with Statistical Applications](http://books.google.ca/books?id=zF1kkWU_fmQC&pg=PA242&dq=moment%20generating%20function%20independent%20if%20and%20only%20if&hl=en&sa=X&ei=h7J5UoaRNuGfyQGQtIGACw&ved=0CEIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=moment%20generating%20function%20independent%20if%20and%20only%20if&f=false), By Rinaldo B. Schinazi. Or page 259 of
[Econometric Analysis of Count Data](http://books.google.ca/books?id=mFi05v3OVE0C&pg=PA259&dq=moment%20generating%20function%20independent%20if%20and%20only&hl=en&sa=X&ei=PrF5UvLMNu3iyAHMmgE&ved=0CEEQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=moment%20generating%20function%20independent%20if%20and%20only&f=false) which is based on probability generating function. Just note that "the moment-generating function does not always exist".

Comment: Thanks for solid refs. Yes, was careful to state that original MGF was given at the start and tried to remember to demonstrate that any other MGF I referred to existed as a consequence before I did anything with it! What proof strategies were employed in your refs?

Comment: Did you read the paragraph right after P2 in my 1st reference?

Comment: Ah yes - it's the extension of my suggested proof to vectors. Compare the MGF of the given distribution with the MGF were the components independent; since they are the same and MGFs uniquely determine joint distribution, the joint distribution _is_ the independent one.

Comment: @Stat Isn't it the case that the MGF always exists, but it might not necessarily be finite. I'm under the impression that because the MGF is the integral of a non-negative measurable function it has to exist...